# How to color a link using hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, color, pdf, links

I'm trying to color one word using hyperref package as a homework to school,I was looking for some examples in the internet how to do it...but whatever I did it doesn't work.

My preamble:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[OT4]{polski}
    \usepackage[polish]{babel}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \makeindex
    \usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Źródło tekstu i ilustracji: \href{https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Lem}{Wikipedia}

\end{document}
```

Now In PDF i need to have this looks like this 
 [image]

i guess its color Magenta in package hyperref but i dont know what commands i should use now in my code to color this

Comment: option `colorlinks`, also please post a full minimal example so we have something to just copy and test. We have no idea what your preamble looks like her. BTW: welcome to the site.

Comment: @daleif and where I sould write this?

Comment: `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}` or later on `\hypersetup{colorlinks}`

Comment: and what command i sould use in line with word "Wikipedia" to make it in color Magenta?

Comment: @Julia: There **is** a manual to be read by users ;-)

Comment: Did you try Christians suggestion and then recompile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get colored links, give `hyperref` the `colorlinks` option either as

```
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
```

or after loading `hyperref` issue

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
```

You can control the four hyperref colors via

```
linkcolor=colorname,
citecolor=colorname,
filecolor=colorname,
urlcolor=colorname,
```

where `colorname` is an existing colorname. By default `urlcolor` is magenta under `colorlinks`.